# React: TypeError: [function] is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning React with a code-along portfolio tutorial course. I'm reaching the end of the course, but I've just hit an error and I can't figure out why it's firing. This particular section involves making a blogging feature that allows you to edit blog entries.

> TypeError: _this4.props.handleSuccessfulFormSubmission is not a function

My first idea is that because the course hasn't been updated since 2018, it may be something that's out-of-date. However, I have yet to have hit a major wall like that in the whole 200 hour course. (Maybe I'm due for one, haha.)

My second idea is this: I am using this form code in two different parts of the website (First, on a page to make new posts. Second, here, where you can edit a post). The prop that's being marked as "not a function" is being passed in from that first part of the website, but is throwing an error only in the second use of the component--while it works for the older video tutorial, I'm not sure whether that's currently valid code or not.

There's a *lot* of code, so I hope I've pulled out everything needed to recreate the error.

Child component which is throwing the error:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
};

handleSubmit(event) {

        this.props.handleSuccessfulFormSubmission(response.data.portfolio_blog);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("handleSubmit for blog error", error);
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Parent Component that this particular case is being called from:

```
export default class BlogDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render (
      return (
          <BlogForm
            //unrelated props...
          />
        );
)
```

Parent component where the prop is actually passed in:

```
export default class BlogModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

  handleSuccessfulFormSubmission(blog) {
    this.props.handleSuccessfulNewBlogSubmission(blog);
  }
}

render() {
    return (
        <BlogForm
          handleSuccessfulFormSubmission={this.handleSuccessfulFormSubmission}
        />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is the `ChildComponent` the `BlogForm`? The answer seems straightforward though: you are either not passing the prop when it's needed, or you are passing the prop but as something that's not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not passing required `props` from your calling parent component.

Also I can't see the definition of `handleSuccessfulFormSubmission(blog)` in your calling component.

If you can define that and pass like below code, it may work.

```
export default class BlogDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

  handleSuccessfulFormSubmission(blog){
  //your code
}

render (
      return (
          <BlogForm
            handleSuccessfulFormSubmission={this.handleSuccessfulFormSubmission}
            //other unrelated props...
          />
        );
)
```